# Commit to repo on production after Capistrano deploy

Tags: git, capistrano, capistrano3

For obscure, painful operational reasons, production code needs to check code into the main Git repo.

However, Capistrano 3, on deploy, does:

```
execute :git, :clone, '--mirror', repo_url, repo_path
```

The `--mirror` option, implies `--bare`, which creates the directory structure without the `.git` meta data.

Is there a way to override this in Capistrano 3?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are committing code from the production (which is usually a strict no - you should create a `patch` from the `diff`, and apply it locally and then do a push), I assume you already have access to your production server.

This is a soultion outside the Capistrano framework. You need to do the following:

1. Make the commit on the production site
2. Push it from there (from your server) to your hosting
   2.1. i.e., push it to your hosted repo location (like github/bitbucket/gitlab)
   2.2. Use the `http(s)` url here (because otherwise you might have to set up ssh keys)
3. Pull those changes into your local developer machine
4. Do a fresh deploy with capistrano from your local machine.

However, I would recommend creating a patch and applying it as follows:

1. Go to your production server, don't make any commits there
2. Create a diff file of all existing files, using `git diff > diff.patch.date`
3. Copy this patch file to one of your local systems using `scp server/path/to/diff.patch.date local/path/to/repo`
4. Apply the patch using `git apply diff.patch.date`
5. Add and commit the changes using `git add . && git commit -m "msg"`
6. Now do a cap deploy

**EDIT**

After re-reading your question, it seems that Capistrano is creating a bare repo, and hence you are unable to make the commits from there. If that is the case,

1. Just make another non bare clone of the repo using `git clone original_bare_rep non_bare_repo`
2. Add your gitlab/bitbucket url etc as a remote using `git remote add upstream url/to/repo/hosting`
3. commit your changes and push them to upstream
4. You can now do a fresh cap deploy, or push to the bare repo directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mu.  I was specifically looking config options for Cap 3 to override this behavior.  Creating a separate repo would work, but I would like to avoid it if possible.  I may just go with overriding the Cap task with a non --mirror version